# How do I aspect fit the zoomed part of an Image using UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm using `self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;` to aspect fit my image inside `UIScrollView` and inside gesture handling function I have this,

```
[self.myScrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(xZoomRect, yZoomRect, widthZoomRect, heightZoomRect) animated:YES];
```

but when I zoom into a part with `zoomToRect` method it doesn't move beyond the bounds of the `contentSize`.

For example, in the following image, orange rectangle is my image and I want to zoom into the blue part of the image. So I passed it's `origin` and `size` values to `zoomToRect`

[image]

but when I zoom in using `zoomToRect` it gets zoomed in in the following manner,

[image]

What I actually want is this,

[image]

How do I aspect fit the zoomed part of the image even when the part of the image to zoom is on the edge of the image, like I have described in the above images?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

use

```
self.myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```